# How to find best combination of lists in Prolog

Tags: matrix, prolog

I have the following problem i want to solve.

I have 2 (or more) matrices; a and b.

Each matrix has column, row and value (profit).

I want to use prolog to find the combination of 2 columns from the 2 different matrices that will give me the most number of positive profits.

I.E. ColumnX in matrix A + ColumnY in matrix B, and then I count the number of values in the result column that has a positive number. I.E. I add the values that are on the same row.

I put the code below that I have tried so far (and a link to it), but my function **count_profits(ColA, ColB, P)** is not returning the expected results. The following query should return **P = 2**, but it returned **P = 1**.

```
 count_profits(66,65.5,P).
```

For now I am providing the column index for each matrix to use. Eventually I want to have a function called **best_profit(ColA, ColB)** that should give me the column from matrix A and the column from matrix B, that results in the most number of positive results when combined. From the test data I have, this should result in **ColA = 66** and **ColB = 65.5** if I am correct.

https://pastebin.com/rKG8twE1

```
    % Data sets 
    % a(Column, Row, Profit)
    % b(Column, Row, Profit)    

    a(65, 66, -0.82).
    a(65, 65.5, -1.32).
    a(65, 65, -1.82).

    a(65.5, 66, -1.07).
    a(65.5, 65.5, -1.57).
    a(65.5, 65, -1.57).

    a(66, 66, -1.3).
    a(66, 65.5, -1.3).
    a(66, 65, -1.3).

    b(65, 66, -1).
    b(65, 65.5, -0.5).
    b(65, 65, 1.72).

    b(65.5, 66, -0.5).
    b(65.5, 65.5, 1.48).
    b(65.5, 65, 1.48).

    b(66, 66, 1.25).
    b(66, 65.5, 1.25).
    b(66, 65, 1.25).

    min_row(Row) :-
        a(Col, Row, _),
        \+ (a(_,Row2,_), Row2 < Row),!.

    max_row(Row) :-
        a(Col, Row, _),
        \+ (a(_,Row2,_), Row2 > Row),!.

    is_profit(ColA, ColB, Row, P) :-
        a(ColA, Row, Profit1),
        b(ColB, Row, Profit2),
        Profit is Profit1 + Profit2,
        ( Profit > 0 -> P is 1 ; P is 0),!.

    count_profits(ColA, ColB, Row1, P) :-
        max_row(Row),
        Row1 =:= Row,
        is_profit(ColA, ColB, Row1, P).

    count_profits(ColA, ColB, Row1, P) :-
        a(ColA,Row2,_),
        Row2 > Row1,
        count_profits(ColA, ColB, Row2, P2),
        is_profit(ColA, ColB, Row1, P1),
        P is P1+P2.

    count_profits(ColA, ColB, P) :-
        min_row(Row1),
        count_profits(ColA, ColB, Row1, P),!.
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is a visual representation of the data I am trying to work with in my sample prolog code:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the comment, *... ColumnX in matrix A + ColumnY in matrix B*. Where are you adding the values of columns A and B? It's a little unclear how you're algorithm is supposed to work.

Comment: *...results in the most number of positive results when combined*. Combined in what way?

Comment: sorry if i'm not clear.
In my sample code the first entry for A is a[65, 66, -0.82] and first entry for B is b[65, 66, -1]. So, for both of them 65 is the column, 66 is the row and -0..82 and -1 is the profit value for A and B. So combining them should give a profit of -1.82.
So when I combine Column '65' from A and Column '65' from A, it should take each row, one at a time (the second value in my a and b functions), and sum the last value in those lists.

Comment: I added an image to my original question, to try clear things up a bit.

Comment: That helped a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I give you a few building blocks to solve this task.

First, let us decide to reason about **rational** numbers. Please avoid the mess of *floating point* numbers, it will cause you endless problems.

To reason about rational numbers in Prolog, check out **CLP(Q)**, constraint solving over *rational numbers*.

In your case, you *start* with matrices involving floating point numbers. Let us first use a more convenient representation for them, for example:

```
matrix(a, [[-0.82,-1.07,-1.3],
           [-1.32,-1.57,-1.3],
           [-1.82,-1.57,-1.3]]).

matrix(b, [[-1,-0.5,1.25],
           [-0.5,1.48,1.25],
           [1.72,1.48,1.25]]).
```

You can use all solutions predicates like `setof/3` and `findall/3` to *convert* your current presentation to such *lists of rows*.

As already mentioned, we should first *convert* this to **rational numbers**, to get rid of many problems in subsequent steps. By the way, there is no guarantee that even the numbers you currently have are represented exactly! Also, in your case, we are mainly interested in the *columns*, so we can **transpose** the matrix and also use `rationalize/1` to obtain *lists of columns* of rational numbers:

```
:- use_module(library(clpq)).
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

to_rational(F, R) :- R is rationalize(F).

rational_columns(Name, Cols) :-
        matrix(Name, Rows),
        transpose(Rows, Cols0),
        maplist(maplist(to_rational), Cols0, Cols).
```

Let us see what we have so far:

```
?- rational_columns(a, Cols).
Cols = [[-41 rdiv 50, -33 rdiv 25, -91 rdiv 50], [-107 rdiv 100, -157 rdiv 100, -157 rdiv 100], [-13 rdiv 10, -13 rdiv 10, -13 rdiv 10]].
```

Moving on, let us define what **addition of columns** means:

```
column_column_plus(As, Bs, Ps) :-
        maplist(addition, As, Bs, Ps).

addition(A, B, Sum) :- { Sum = A + B }.
```

This uses CLP(Q) constraints to define the element-wise addition of lists. It is usable in all directions!

Using these building blocks, we can already describe the *combinations of columns* we are interested in:

```
combination_number(A-B, N) :-
        rational_columns(a, ACs),
        rational_columns(b, BCs),
        member(A, ACs),
        member(B, BCs),
        column_column_plus(A, B, Ps),
        include(<(0), Ps, Gs0),
        Gs0 = [_|_],
        length(Gs0, N).
```

The solutions are found on backtracking:

```
?- combination_number(Cs, N).
Cs = [-41 rdiv 50, -33 rdiv 25, -91 rdiv 50]-[-1 rdiv 2, 37 rdiv 25, 37 rdiv 25],
N = 1 ;
Cs = [-41 rdiv 50, -33 rdiv 25, -91 rdiv 50]-[5 rdiv 4, 5 rdiv 4, 5 rdiv 4],
N = 1 ;
Cs = [-107 rdiv 100, -157 rdiv 100, -157 rdiv 100]-[-1, -1 rdiv 2, 43 rdiv 25],
N = 1 ;
Cs = [-107 rdiv 100, -157 rdiv 100, -157 rdiv 100]-[5 rdiv 4, 5 rdiv 4, 5 rdiv 4],
N = 1 ;
Cs = [-13 rdiv 10, -13 rdiv 10, -13 rdiv 10]-[-1, -1 rdiv 2, 43 rdiv 25],
N = 1 ;
Cs = [-13 rdiv 10, -13 rdiv 10, -13 rdiv 10]-[-1 rdiv 2, 37 rdiv 25, 37 rdiv 25],
N = 2 ;
false.
```

To select an **optimum** combination, you can use `findall/3` in combination with `keysort/2`:

```
?- findall(N-Cs, combination_number(Cs, N), NCs0),
   keysort(NCs0, NCs),
   last(NCs, Best).
```

Yielding:

```
Best = 2-([-13 rdiv 10, -13 rdiv 10, -13 rdiv 10]-[-1 rdiv 2, 37 rdiv 25, 37 rdiv 25]).
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I will try it out. For the rational number issue, i will just multiply all my numbers by 100 (outside of prolog), might make things simpler.
It seems by biggest issue was the way i was storing or presenting the information in my Prolog program.
I'll mark this answer as answered once i've tested some of the stuff here.

Comment: Perfect! If you are using integers, check out CLP(FD) constraints for declarative arithmetic, instead of CLP(Q) as I wrote above.